# How to open DataSet in Visual Studio 2008 faster?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, optimization, dataset

When I open DataSet in Visual Studio 2008 to design or modify it, it always take a very long time (more than five minutes) before I can continue to do my job. While I'm waiting I can't do anything on Visual Studio, moreover CPU and memory usage is growth dramatically.

I want to know, Is it has anyway to reduce this waiting time?

Hardware - Desktop
CPU: Intel Q6600
Memory: 4 GB
HDD: 320 GB 7200 rpm
OS: Windows XP 32 bit with Service Pack 3

Comment: 1) Defrag your hard drive with PerfectDisk. 2) Clear out all of Visual Studio's temporary and system's temporary files. 3) Delete the solutions .suo file, you will lose user project settings, such as breakpoints. 4) If you move data set to a new project, do you still have the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

Go to the Options -> Windows Form Designer and set the AutoToolboxPopulate to false. It worked for some of my team members who work with DataSet.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working with SQL Server datasets, maybe you should try using SQL Management Studio. It may be more tailored for that sort of work.

If not, what kind of datasets are you using, and why are they so large?

Comment: He's using the DataSet designer to work with the design of the DataSet - he's not looking at data.

Answer (score -1):

You could try ASYNC to avoid blocking if you want to process something else while you are waiting. An event would fire to indicate data has been loaded.

Hope that help,